# Create a list going depending on a dataset in R

Tags: r, networking, bioinformatics

I have a dataset of dimensions 256544x2. The structure is something like this:

```
gene 1   group1
gene 2   group1
gene 3   group1
gene 4   group1
gene 5   group2
gene 6   group2
gene 2   group2
gene 7   group2
gene 3   group3
gene 5   group3
gene 8   group3
```

What I want to do is to extract the genes that each group has and store it in a list. I was thinking doing it with several for and if loops, but I am sure it will be an easier way that is out of my scope.

The idea would be to have a list:

```
set1: (gene 1,gene 2, gene 3, gene 4)
set2: (gene 5, gene 6, gene 2, gene 7)
...                          .....
```

setn=......

Comment: Are you looking for  `split()` ?

Comment: In particular, `split(df$var1, df$var2)` should produce a list where the names of each item correspond to the group name in your dataset.

Comment: Thank both! It was exactly what I wanted.